# Does it help to start intensive core animation blocks in another thread?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an scroll view with some sophisticated animations happening during scrolling. Although after 2 weeks of finetuning the performance is acceptable now, the scrolling is not 100% smooth when the animations happen.

I know that core animation does animations in a background thread. But I wonder if it would help to split those animation blocks (10 of them at pretty much the same time) into threads.

There are a few methods that look interesting:

– performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
– performSelectorInBackground:withObject:

or is that nonsense to do?

Comment: (re duplicates, now deleted) Please try to only ask the question once...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, it won't help**. As you correctly stated yourself, Core Animation already runs in a seperate thread. Core Animation is smart enough to handle animation blocks as efficiently as possible. I wouldn't advise interfering with it.

The [Core Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/WhatisCoreAnimation.html) says:

> An abstract animation interface that
>   allows animations to run on a separate
>   thread, independent of your
>   application's run loop. Once an
>   animation is configured and starts,
>   Core Animation assumes full
>   responsibility for running it at frame
>   rate.

Comment: Well, that's true. But since I make a lot of blocks, I wonder if they're going to run all in the same thread?

Comment: Yes they will. Question is, will it look pretty. :)

Comment: Of course, as always, you'll only know if you try. I guess this question has to do with the one where I advise using OpenGL?

Comment: Yep, that's right. You're totally right with OpenGL. But for this project I want to stick to CA. Just for learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the choppy behavior is really from CA?  Do you have anything else going on?

If you have any background network access, consider moving that into a separate thread - the time taken to service those calls takes away from time the UI spends updating the screen as you scroll.

Comment: no, there's nothing going on. Indeed I had some preloading code, but that caused a worse performance than without any preloading. I ended up loading all views in the scrollview at once at the beginning, since they're not many anyways.